# Local Image isn't shown in first component without any error but not shown in it's detail component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I have blog component and details component where in single post's details is read as shown below .

Point to be noted
The blog component can load and render the image but the blog details component can't . why ?

[image]

And blog details component .

[image]

directory structure :

```
blog>
    blog.js
    blogdetails.js
```

the json data locally hosted which is same for both componet blog component and single blog component

```
{
  "title": "Thirst Craft Gives Brooklyn Brewery’s Hazy IPA A Juicy Pop Art Makeover",
  "body": "If you ever wanted to know what a Milton Glaser logo would look like if it went through a pop art filter, then Brooklyn Brewery's Hazy IPA is likely what you’d get. And it’s a bright, bold, and incredibly playful addition to your beer cozy.",
  "author": "Hasnain",
  "id": 2,
  "img": "pics/nasa2.jpg"
}
```

I have tried many solutions , and checked .
All the properties is rendered but only img can't be  rendred in blog details component .

[image]

Single post (blogdetails)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with require to import the image as follows

```
<img src={require({props.img})} />
```